# MacOS not POSIX compliant?

Tags: c, macos, file, operating-system, posix

Here's a program that doesn't compile on MacOS, but [should](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/open.html):

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int main ()
{
  open("main.c", O_RDWR | O_RSYNC);
}
```

Looking at the provided system man-page, it doesn't mention `O_RSYNC`, and it also doesn't mention `O_DSYNC` and `O_SYNC`, but this compiles:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int main ()
{
  open("main.c", O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_DSYNC);
}
```

so my question is: what gives? Is this a common practice, for things not to be POSIX compliant and also to have undocumented options? What behavior should I rely on here, and does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`O_RSYNC` is flagged with an "SIO" tag defined as

> [SIO] [Option Start] Synchronized Input and Output [Option End]
> The functionality described is optional. The functionality described is also an extension to the ISO C standard.

POSIX doesn't require the implementation of this feature.

[Source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)

Comment: So to port to MacOS, one would have to define it conditionally as a no-op (like `#define O_RSYNC 0`, when detecting one is on a MacOS system?

Comment: The solution would depend on the effect the use of `O_RSYNC` is trying to achieve. This outside of the scope of this Question and Answer.

Comment: @user129393192: Why would you make the test specific to macOS? Your concern is whether or not `O_RSYNC` is supported. So use `#if ! defined O_RSYNC`.